# Finding most general matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $A\cdot B=1$

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, constraint

I would like to find the most general shape of matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $A\cdot B=1_{4\times4}$. Naively, I just define for example

```
AA = Table[Subscript[aa, i, j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 5}];
BB = Table[Subscript[bb, i, j], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 4}];
```

And look for the solution set of

```
Solve[(AA.BB // Flatten) == (IdentityMatrix[4] // Flatten), Variables[{AA, BB}]]
```

However, unfortunately this calculation goes on indefinitely, never producing a result for some reason. Therefore, I'd like to ask if there is a more clever way to do it? Note that I just want $A$ to be the left inverse of $B$, while $B\cdot A$ does not necessarily equal $1$. Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: `AA` and `Inverse[AA]` would be an admissible pair, no?

Comment: I believe that would be too restrictive, since these two are simultaneously left and right inverses of each other.

Comment: I see, so your matrices can be singular, then?

Comment: Yes, singular matrices are OK. In this sense, I guess it was silly of me to try the `Solve` command in the first place, since singular matrices would be excluded by solubility of the system... But I am definitely looking for the most general set of such matrices, including singular.

Comment: I might suggest trying to solve the problem in 2D first. After all, if you can't do it in 2D, there is little hope for 4D!

Comment: Actually, providing too many variables to the routine made it slow. If we put `Solve[(AA.BB // Flatten) == (IdentityMatrix[4] // Flatten), Variables[{AA}]]`, an answer is generated immediately, yet it is just the regular inverse. OK, starting with 2D is a good idea!

Comment: Then, have you looked into the Moore-Penrose conditions?

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for the hint! I just looked them up and it says the pseudo inverse under these conditions is unique, which makes it most general. So those are the equations to solve.

Comment: @J.M., Kagaratsch,  If A is square, then A.B = I implies A is nonsingular and has a two-sided inverse, and it is given by B, no? So J.M.'s first comment is the answer. If Kagaratsch is really interested in rectangular matrices, then giving only a square example and not mentioning the full scope of the question seems misleading. It misled me.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That is a good point! I will edit the question to make it more general.

Comment: There are none. Your matrices have rank at most 3, they cannot give a product of rank 4.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you for pointing this out. I adjusted the question again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem.**
*Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ matrix and $B$.
To find all $m \times n$ matrices $B$ satisfying $AB = I$.*

Let $p,q$ be the rank, nullity (respectively) of $A$ so that $p+q=m$.
The condition $AB = I$ implies $p \ge n$ and the dimensions of $A$ imply $p \le n$; therefore the rank of $A$ being $p = n$ is a necessary condition.
Let $A^+$ be any left inverse of $A$, such as the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Definition), so that $AA^+=I$.
Let $C$ be an $m \times n$ matrix whose columns are chosen from the null space of $A$.
Then if $B = A^+ + C$, then $AB = I$.

Conversely, if $AB_1 = AB_2 = I$, then $A(B_1-B_2) = 0$ and the columns of $B_1-B_2$ are elements of the null space of $A$.

Therefore, if the rank of $A$ is less than $n$, there are no such $B$; if the rank is $n$, then the general solution is given by $B = A^+ +C$, where the columns of $C$ belong to the null space of $A$.

*Remark.*  If $A$ is square and there is a matrix $B$ such that $AB=I$,
then $A$ is invertible and $B = A^{-1}$ is the only solution.

---

It seems more like a mathematics quesion, but here is some code to find the general left inverse for a made-up matrix.  (In *Mathematica*, the pseudoinverse is computed with [`PseudoInverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PseudoInverse.html).)

```
b = PseudoInverse[
     a = {{1, 1, 2, 0, 1},
          {0, 2, 2, 2, 0},
          {0, 0, 0, 1, 1} }];
With[{nsb = NullSpace[a]},
  c = Transpose@ Table[Sum[C[i, j] nsb[[i]], {i, Length@nsb}], {j, Length@a}]]
b + c // MatrixForm
a.(b + c) // Simplify // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

This seems to give a reasonable answer in n=2 and n=3 dimensions:

```
n = 2; aa = Array[a, {n, n}]; bb = Array[b, {n, n}];
Reduce[(aa.bb // Flatten) == (IdentityMatrix[n] // Flatten), Variables[bb]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to a hint by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) I looked up the [Moore-Penrose conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore-Penrose_pseudoinverse#Definition). They describe a unique generalization of the inverse to singular matrices, which reduces to the regular inverse for non-singular matrices. Property 3) and 4) state that the multiplication of pseudoinverse $A^+$ and matrix $A$ has to be hermitian. If we want this multiplication to definitely yield the unit matrix (and not just a hermitian matrix), we have to assume that either rows or columns of $A$ are linearly independent. I.e. for linearly independent rows we get

$$A^+=A^*(AA^*)^{-1}$$

since then $AA^+=1$. Therefore, in the language of the question above

```
BB=Conjugate[AA].Inverse[AA.Conjugate[AA]]
```

is the most general right inverse of a matrix `AA` with linearly independent rows. Similarly

```
AA=Inverse[Conjugate[BB].BB].Conjugate[BB]
```

is the most general left inverse of a matrix `BB` with linearly independent columns.